# How can I search a database based on multiple, dynamic criteria?

Tags: search, database-design

Scenario: I'm building a web app that pairs programmers, designers, business people, etc. based on a user's search criteria.

How can I return the most relevant search results based on the criteria entered by the person searching?

For example: A business user searching for a programmer with PHP, Angular, MySQL skills.

Each skill would be a separate tag (Tag1 = PHP, Tag2 = Angular, Tag 3 = MySQL) and so each "person" object would be made up of a different combination of this data.

Is there a more elegant way to query the database rather than have a column in the person table for each skill and have the query run the search based on the presence of said skill?

I guess rather than multiple columns I could also build a 1:MANY relationship between person and skills and only return results containing said skills. I feel like this would return more rows than necessary though.

A more specific example is how Stackoverflow allows you to tag a question with multiple tags...How are these tags/questions searched and stored in the DB?

Comment: Regarding your last question: since the number of tags on SO is limited (to 5) it is probably a fixed set of columns, or an array (both would violate 1NF, but that is not as hamfull as it seems, if it can be handled in code)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you are using.  If your database handles array-based searches well (for example, as PostgreSQL does), then that would be preferable to a fixed set of columns for searching performance reasons.

Now a big issue you may have is with synonyms.  What if someone searches for Postgres instead of PostgreSQL?

In one of my projects we repurposed PostgreSQL's full text search for something like this.  In this case you could have an array of words, which get turned into a tsvector, and with a set of synonyms you could have normalization of spellings, stemming, synonyms, etc.  It is one way to address this problem but requires some extra code (and maybe a trigger).